# Getting "Malformed auth code" when calling https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

Tags: google-api, google-play-developer-api

I'm getting "Malformed Auth Code" message after trying to call POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token in https://reqbin.com/.

I've followed this [link](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization) and made API calls before, but this time, after the first step, the code starts with "4%" instead of "4/" like in the example and previous successful calls. I believe this difference is causing the issue. I've tried replacing the percent sigh with the backslash, but it didn't work.

Could you please advise? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Turns out the code needs to be decoded from URL encoded format. I used this site.

https://www.urldecoder.org/

When did Google made the change?